Flutter - I can't handle deep links with complex pattern on android
Problem:
I am encountering challenges in handling deep links for your Android app when dealing with complex website URLs for products and categories. These URLs contain dynamic IDs (-c-${category_id} for categories and -p${product_id} for products), causing issues with pattern matching in the AndroidManifest.xml.
Examples:

Category URL: https://www.medexsepeti.com/dental-sarf-c-2671

Product URL: https://www.medexsepeti.com/pudrali-lateks-eldiven-100-lu-p38714?v=15145


Desired Behavior:
I want these deep links to launch your app and direct users to the corresponding product or category within the app, enhancing the user experience by providing seamless navigation.
Explanation:
The inherent complexity of dynamic IDs in your website's URLs makes it difficult to accurately define static patterns in the AndroidManifest.xml using the pathPattern attribute. While this approach might work for simpler URLs, it becomes unreliable for dynamic content.
image from app manifest

app_links: ^6.3.2
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application>
        <activity>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="medexsepeti.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="medexsepeti.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

class DeepLinkConfiguration {
  DeepLinkConfiguration();
  final appLinks = AppLinks();
  StreamSubscription<Uri>? sub;
  void initDeepLinkListener(context) async {
    sub = appLinks.uriLinkStream.listen((uri) async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
      _handleDeepLink(uri,context);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _handleDeepLink(uri,context) async {
    final productId = uri.pathSegments.last;
    // Code to redirect
  }

ON MAIN INIT STATE
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _deepLinkConfiguration = DeepLinkConfiguration();
      _deepLinkConfiguration.initDeepLinkListener(context);
    });
  }

But remember you can only test deep link if you build your app with release mode, and if you publish it on playstore add playstore SHA-1
on

may be available on
https://www.medexsepeti.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

the issue is it opens all the URLs with the host name of medexsepeti.com, I need to open specific URLs in the app itself others should open in browser.

android:pathPrefix="/product/"
on visit medexsepeti.com/product/myoriductid
this will open only on path after /product/
you AdnroidManifiest.xml allow all link after medexsepeti.com to open
